# CloudFormation create Stack only if Condition is valid and show custom error message if not valid

Tags: amazon-web-services, conditional-statements, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create CF template that will ask users if RDS Instance and SecurityGroup exists and if they select Yes, then create the stack. If not, warn user that to create RDS Instance and SecurityGroup before creating the EC2 Stack.

```
Parameters:
 IsRDSCreated:
  Description: Ensure that the RDS Instance is already created
  Default: No
  Type: String
  AllowedValues:
   - Yes
   - No
 IsRDSSGCreated:
  Description: Ensure that the RDS Security Group exists
  Default: No
  Type: String
  AllowedValues:
   - Yes
   - No
Conditions:
 ShouldCreateEC2Resource: !And
  - !Equals [!Ref IsRDSCreated, Yes]
  - !Equals [!Ref IsRDSSGCreated, Yes]
Resources:
 EC2Instance:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Condition: ShouldCreateEC2Resource
  .....
  .....
  .....
  .....
```

At the moment, when I try to create after both the parameter is set to False, I get Template validation error: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [EC2Instance] in the Resources block of the template.

How can I notify users with some kind of error/message that when they select False and run this, to make sure both RDS instance and RDS SG present before creating this stack.

Please suggest if there any other ways or methods of accomplishing this stack.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm getting what exactly do you want to achieve. Do you plan to validate the template then raise an error/notify the user about the error of the template without actually bootstrapping the stack in AWS?

Comment: Yes, in the CF console when we choose the template and select the Parameters, in this case we select False and in the final screen we click Create.

Then, the following Error message is displayed - "

    Error
    Template validation error: Template format error: Unresolved resource 
    dependencies [EC2Instance] in the Resources block of the template."

I would like to show some message in the console like "RDS instance and RDS SG should be created before creating this stack and select True for IsRDSCreated and IsRDSSGCreated parameter"

Comment: would it be better that instead of having the Yes/No choices for `IsRDSSGCreated` and `IsRDSCreated` parameter, you will require the user to input the values of the parameter `RDSSG` and ` `RDS`?